# Recursive Method: Columns and Rows (Grid)

Tags: java, recursion, methods, grid, rows

I need to develop a recursive method that will allow the user to input two numbers, (say, 6 and 5) and give me a grid shaped like this:

$ $ $ $ $

$ $ $ $ $

$ $ $ $ $

$ $ $ $ $

$ $ $ $ $

with 5 columns and 6 rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Language is Java, and so far nothing I've tried is close to working. I'm trying to base it off of some problems in the book I'm using but having no luck.

Comment: The example you have given only has 5 rows. It should have 6

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simlpe c# one that does that. You'll have to change the write line to java i guess, but it should work the same.

You'll call it with     `print_rec(4,2);`, and it'll call another recursive call that will do the work. do notice that we want the rows-1 and columns-1 because otherwise you'll get an extra one (if you compare to 0, you could ofcourse stop the recursion when you reach 1, but it's confusing).
Also note that we need an extra variable to remember the position of current printed character.

```
public void print_rec (int rows, int columns {
    rec1(rows-1,columns-1,columns-1);
}

public void recursive_print(int rows, int columns, int current) {
    Console.Out.Write("#");
    if (rows==0 && current ==0)
        return;
    else if (current == 0) {
    Console.Out.WriteLine();
        rec1 (rows-1, columns, columns);}
    else
        rec1 (rows, columns, current-1);
}
```